# VS Code: "go to next problem" in current file rather than in any file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I starting to use VS Code with Purescript and Haskell. The VS Code function "Go to next problem" is very handy, except that it goes to any problem (including warnings) in *any* file. I would like it to go to the next problem in *this* file.

Alternatively, is there a way to see warnings or errors without needing to use the mouse to hover over them? "Go to next problem" does that with a peek window, but otherwise it's annoying to have to take my hands off the keyboard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm using Code Insiders.

In Code you can use: (type in ctrl + shift + p console)

```
Go to next problem(Error, Warning, Info).
```

This loops over the errors in current file, never changes file.

When you run f8, this starts other command

```
Go to next problem in Files (Error, Warning, Info)
```

Just add some shortcut to first one

Comment: FYI this has a default shortcut now (at least on Mac):

⌥F8: Go to Next Problem (...)   ; F8: Go to Next Problem in Files (...)

Answer (score 3):

`Alt+F8` is difficult for me so I use a custom binding. The command name is the rather cryptic

```
editor.action.marker.next
```

mine is assigned like so:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+numpad1",
  "command": "editor.action.marker.next",
  "when": "editorFocus"
},
```